# Tornado as normal server

Tags: python, tornado

How to listen for the connections on Tornado Web Server coming not from local network? Default it listening only for connection from localhost. I have tried tips from Django to start it listening on address 0.0.0.0 but this doesn't work.

Some simple code:

```
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
server.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

BY default the tornado httpserver will listen on the specified port for all net interfaces (IP addresses). So, passing the port *only* should work fine.

You also need to be sure to start the ioloop instance that the server is using:

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The [tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide.html) are very good.

Comment: So now I'm dunno. I'm tryin to run project [FemHub Online Lab](https://github.com/certik/femhub-online-lab) as service to have access from other computers (most important is core), but when I can get access to it from local machine (localhost, LAN IP and WAN IP, I have forwarded ports) I have no problems, but when I try to connect from virtual machine or my server I can't access. Even if I modified sources to add missing address parm.

Comment: Only had a brief look but it seems to me that that app _does_ configure the tornado HTTPServer instance to listen on all interfaces. See https://github.com/certik/femhub-online-lab/blob/master/onlinelab/core/runtime.py#L202, no address param is being passed.

Comment: Yes, I founded this and according to your words is should work, but it didn't. I have no idea. Only solution which I can use is to start tornado as backend and ex. nginix as main webserver. This should end with all limitations.

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant config (port, address etc) that you are using, and also some details of your server (it's IP, what OS is it). I'll have a think

Comment: For development I run this script on my own computer. In a sec I will put it on my server to deeply test it.

Comment: I only have access to FreeBsd and OSX right now so I can't run the whole app (which requires inotify, which is linux only). However, I can run the 'core' with `bin/onlinelab core start --no-daemon --home=../core-home`. I have made no modifications and I _can_ access it using the external IP of my machine on port 8000.

Comment: BTW, if you have any relationship with the maintainers, tell them that the prerequisites listed in INSTALL.rst are incomplete. pycurl, docutils, pysqlite2 and pygments are also required. Further, there seems to be a bug in the two `runtime.py` files; The attempt to import `daemon.pidlockfile` fails. I think it should be `lockfile.pidlockfile`

Answer (score 4):

I found this question while trying trying to diagnose a similar issue (tornado server running on computer A, inaccessible from computer B).

I eventually figured it out, I needed to open the port on computer A's firewall.